IDs remain duplicates when planting information through Bogus
IDs remain duplicates when planting information through Bogus. I have User and UserAddress tables. Foreign keys in UserAddress remain duplicates. That is, User IDs are repeated in the UserAddress table.
public DatabaseSeeder()
{
Users = GenerateUsers(amount: 30);
UserAddresses = GenerateUserAddresses(amount: 30, Users);
}

private static IReadOnlyCollection<User> GenerateUsers(int amount)
{
    var fakerUsers = new Faker<User>()
        .RuleFor(u => u.Id, _ => Guid.NewGuid())
        .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, f => f.Name.FirstName())
        .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, f => f.Name.LastName())
        .RuleFor(u => u.PhoneNumber, f => f.Phone.PhoneNumber())
        .RuleFor(u => u.DateBorth, f => f.Date.Between(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70), DateTime.Now))
        .RuleFor(u => u.Sex, f => f.PickRandom(new[] { "Male", "Female" }));

    var users = Enumerable.Range(1, amount)
        .Select(i => SeedRow(fakerUsers, i))
        .GroupBy(u  => u.Id)
        .Select(u => u.First())
        .ToList();

    return users;
}

private static IReadOnlyCollection<UserAddress> GenerateUserAddresses(int amount, IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    var fakerUserAddresses = new Faker<UserAddress>()
        .RuleFor(ua => ua.Id, _ => Guid.NewGuid())
        .RuleFor(ua => ua.City, f => f.Address.City())
        .RuleFor(ua => ua.UserId, f => f.PickRandom(users).Id);

    var userAddresses = Enumerable.Range(1, amount)
        .Select(i => SeedRow(fakerUserAddresses, i))
        .ToList();

    return userAddresses;
}

Error message

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserAddresses' with unique index 'IX_UserAddresses_UserId'. The duplicate key value is (5247165f-362d-4fdc-a04e-51e29c327e94).
The statement has been terminated

I expected the UserAddress table to store the User's ids without duplicates, but Bogus's PickRandom method duplicates the ids, what is the solution?
